# Portable C++ Stack Trace on Exception

Tags: c++, portability, stack-trace

I am writing a library that I would like to be portable.  Thus, it should not depend on glibc or Microsoft extensions or anything else that is not in the standard.  I have a nice hierarchy of classes derived from std::exception that I use to handle errors in logic and input.  Knowing that a particular type of exception was thrown at a particular file and line number is useful, but knowing how the execution got there would be potentially much more valuable, so I have been looking at ways of acquiring the stack trace.

I am aware that this data is available when building against glibc using the functions in execinfo.h (see [question 76822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76822/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-c-app-crashes-using-gcc-compiler)) and through the StackWalk interface in Microsoft's C++ implementation (see [question 126450](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126450/call-stack-at-runtime)), but I would very much like to avoid anything that is not portable.

I was thinking of implementing this functionality myself in this form:

```
class myException : public std::exception
{
public:
  ...
  void AddCall( std::string s )
  { m_vCallStack.push_back( s ); }
  std::string ToStr() const
  {
    std::string l_sRet = "";
    ...
    l_sRet += "Call stack:\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < m_vCallStack.size(); i++ )
      l_sRet += "  " + m_vCallStack[i] + "\n";
    ...
    return l_sRet;
  }
private:
  ...
  std::vector< std::string > m_vCallStack;
};

ret_type some_function( param_1, param_2, param_3 )
{
  try
  {
    ...
  }
  catch( myException e )
  {
    e.AddCall( "some_function( " + param_1 + ", " + param_2 + ", " + param_3 + " )" );
    throw e;
  }
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
  try
  {
    ...
  }
  catch ( myException e )
  {
    std::cerr << "Caught exception: \n" << e.ToStr();
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is this a terrible idea?  It would mean a lot of work adding try/catch blocks to every function, but I can live with that.  It would not work when the cause of the exception is memory corruption or lack of memory, but at that point you are pretty much screwed anyway.  It may provide misleading information if some functions in the stack do not catch exceptions, add themselves to the list, and rethrow, but I can at least provide a guarantee that all of my library functions do so.  Unlike a "real" stack trace I will not get the line number in calling functions, but at least I would have something.

My primary concern is the possibility that this will cause a slowdown even when no exceptions are actually thrown.  Do all of these try/catch blocks require an additional set-up and tear-down on each function invocation, or is somehow handled at compile-time?  Or are there other issues I have not considered?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is a really bad idea.

Portability is a very worthy goal, but not when it results in a solution that is intrusive, performance-sapping, and an inferior implementation.

Every platform (Windows/Linux/PS2/iPhone/etc) I've worked on has offered a way to walk the stack when an exception occurs and match addresses to function names. Yes, none of these are portable but the reporting framework can be and it usually takes less than a day or two to write a platform-specific version of stack walking code.

Not only is this less time than it'd take creating/maintaining a cross-platform solution, but the results are far better;

- No need to modify functions
- Traps crashes in standard or third party libraries
- No need for a try/catch in every function (slow and memory intensive)

Answer (score 6):

Look up `Nested Diagnostic Context` once. Here is a little hint:

```
class NDC {
public:
    static NDC* getContextForCurrentThread();
    int addEntry(char const* file, unsigned lineNo);
    void removeEntry(int key);
    void dump(std::ostream& os);
    void clear();
};

class Scope {
public:
    Scope(char const *file, unsigned lineNo) {
       NDC *ctx = NDC::getContextForCurrentThread();
       myKey = ctx->addEntry(file,lineNo);
    }
    ~Scope() {
       if (!std::uncaught_exception()) {
           NDC *ctx = NDC::getContextForCurrentThread();
           ctx->removeEntry(myKey);
       }
    }
private:
    int myKey;
};
#define DECLARE_NDC() Scope s__(__FILE__,__LINE__)

void f() {
    DECLARE_NDC(); // always declare the scope
    // only use try/catch when you want to handle an exception
    // and dump the stack
    try {
       // do stuff in here
    } catch (...) {
       NDC* ctx = NDC::getContextForCurrentThread();
       ctx->dump(std::cerr);
       ctx->clear();
    }
}
```

The overhead is in the implementation of the NDC. I was playing with a lazily evaluated version as well as one that only kept a fixed number of entries as well. The key point is that if you use constructors and destructors to handle the stack so that you don't need all of those nasty `try`/`catch` blocks and explicit manipulation everywhere.

The only platform specific headache is the `getContextForCurrentThread()` method. You can use a platform specific implementation using thread local storage to handle the job in most if not all cases.

If you are more performance oriented and live in the world of log files, then change the scope to hold a pointer to the file name and line number and omit the NDC thing altogether:

```
class Scope {
public:
    Scope(char const* f, unsigned l): fileName(f), lineNo(l) {}
    ~Scope() {
        if (std::uncaught_exception()) {
            log_error("%s(%u): stack unwind due to exception\n",
                      fileName, lineNo);
        }
    }
private:
    char const* fileName;
    unsigned lineNo;
};
```

This will give you a nice stack trace in your log file when an exception is thrown. No need for any real stack walking, just a little log message when an exception is being thrown ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a "platform independent" way to do this - after all, if there was, there wouldn't be a need for StackWalk or the special gcc stack tracing features you mention.

It would be a bit messy, but the way I would implement this would be to create a class that offers a consistent interface for accessing the stack trace, then have #ifdefs in the implementation that use the appropriate platform-specific methods to actually put the stack trace together.

That way your usage of the class is platform independent, and just that class would need to be modified if you wanted to target some other platform.

Answer (score 1):

In the debugger:

To get the stack trace of where an exception is throw from I just stcik the break point in std::exception constructor.

Thus when the exception is created the debugger stops and you can then see the stack trace at that point. Not perfect but it works most of the time.

Comment: He wasn't asking for debugger instructions.

Comment: And this does not help in de-bugging?

Answer (score 1):

Stack managing is one of those simple things that get complicated very quickly. Better leave it for specialized libraries. Have you tried libunwind? Works great and AFAIK it's portable, though I've never tried it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This will be slower but looks like it should work.

From what I understand the problem in making a fast, portable, stack trace is that the stack implementation is both OS and CPU specific, so it is implicitly a platform specific problem. An alternative would be to use the MS/glibc functions and to use #ifdef and appropriate preprocessor defines (e.g. _WIN32) to implement the platform specific solutions in different builds.

Answer (score 0):

Since stack usage is highly platform and implementation dependent, there is no way to do it directly that is completely portable. However, you could build a portable interface to a platform and compiler specific implementation, localizing the issues as much as possible. IMHO, this would be your best approach.

The tracer implementation would then link to whatever platform specific helper libraries are available. It would then operate only when an exception occurs, and even then only if you called it from a catch block.  Its minimal API would simply return a string containing the whole trace.

Requiring the coder to inject catch and rethrow processing in the call chain has significant runtime costs on some platforms, and imposes a large future maintenance cost.

That said, if you do choose to use the catch/throw mechanism, don't forget that even C++ still has the C preprocessor available, and that the macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are defined. You can use them to include the source file name and line number in your trace information.