# C++ get call stack from std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, callstack

how can I print the full call stack when a std::exception raises?

Comment: No way of doing this using standard C++ - your specific compiler may have something you can use.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Which platform are you using, as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691719/c-display-stack-trace-on-exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616653/portable-c-stack-trace-on-exception

Comment: I'm using g++ in debian.

Comment: Don't think you can do this without using a debugger.  Unlike languages like Java stacktrace capturing and reading isn't in the language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes/77336#77336

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using g++ (gcc) and don't mind the code being non-portable, you could try following the wise words of ["tombarta"](http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/c-stack-traces-with-gcc/):

(shameless copy from tombarta):

```
#include <execinfo.h>
void print_trace(FILE *out, const char *file, int line)
{
    const size_t max_depth = 100;
    size_t stack_depth;
    void *stack_addrs[max_depth];
    char **stack_strings;

    stack_depth = backtrace(stack_addrs, max_depth);
    stack_strings = backtrace_symbols(stack_addrs, stack_depth);

    fprintf(out, "Call stack from %s:%d:\n", file, line);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < stack_depth; i++) {
        fprintf(out, "    %s\n", stack_strings[i]);
    }
    free(stack_strings); // malloc()ed by backtrace_symbols
    fflush(out);
}
```

I haven't tried this myself, so I do not know if it works.