# Locating segmentation fault for multithread program running on cluster

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, cluster-computing, hpc

It's quite straightforward to use `gdb` in order to locate a segmentation fault while running a simple program in interactive mode. But consider we have a multithread program - written by `pthread` - submitted to a cluster node (by `qsub` command). So we don't have an interactive operation.

How we can locate the segmentation fault? I am looking for a general approach, a program or test tool. I can not provide a reproducible example as the program is really big and crashes on the cluster in some unknown situations.

I need to find a problem in such hard situation because the program runs correctly on the local machine with any number of threads.

Comment: How large is your cluster? How many nodes does your program require?

Comment: @SamMiller Working on one node of up to 32 cores (threads)

Comment: Do you have a core file?

Comment: @SamMiller The core file is created, but empty!

Comment: what operating system? What cluster management software?

Comment: @SamMiller It's Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon). I access cluster using commands like qsub, qhost, qdel, etc. Is there specific way to find cluster management software?

Comment: It is either Sun Grid Engine (now Oracle Grid Engine or may be Open Grid Scheduler) or PBS (OpenPBS or may be Torque). If you specify the run-time as `-l h_rt=hh:mm:ss` then it's definitely SGE.

Comment: @SamMiller According to the man page of qsub, it is Open Grid Scheduler v6.2u5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "normal" approach is to have the environment produce a core file and get hold of those. If this isn't an option, you might want to try installing a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` which obtains, at least, a stack trace dumped somewhere. Of course, this immediately leads to the question ["how to get a stack trace"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616653/portable-c-stack-trace-on-exception) but this is answered elsewhere.

The easiest approach is probably to get hold of a core file. Assuming you have a similar machine where the core file can be read, you can use `gdb program corefile` to debug the program `program` which produced the core file `corefile`: You should be able to look at the different threads, their data (to some extend), etc. If you don't have a suitable machine it may be necessary to cross-compile `gdb` matching the hardware of the machine where it was run.

I'm a bit confused about the statement that the core files are empty: You can set the limits for core files using `ulimit` on the shell. If the size for cores is set to zero it shouldn't produce any core file. Producing an empty one seems odd. However, if you cannot change the limits on your program you are probably down to installing a signal handler and dumping out a stack trace from the offending thread.

Thinking of it, you may be able to put the program to sleep in the signal handler and attach to it using a debugger, assuming you can run a debugger on the corresponding machine. You would determine the process ID (using, e.g., `ps -elf | grep program`) and then attach to it using

```
gdb program pid
```

I'm not sure how to put a program to sleep from within the program, though (possibly installing the handler for `SIGSTOP` for `SIGSEGV`...).

That said, I assume you tried running your program on your local machine...? Some problems are more fundamental than needing a distributed system of many threads running on each node. This is, obviously, not a replacement for the approach above.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question.I think the core files are generated.

Comment: @Ali: If a core file is generated, get hold of it and see what the situation is! That sounds simple enough.

Comment: Thanks, but reading your proposed page I could find no idea about how to use the core files. It's not so simple for me, the same as you!

Comment: If you use `gdb program corefile` you should be able to have a look at where the program occurs and, to some extend, inspect the content of variables. It assumes that you have a `gdb` capable of reading programs and core files of the architecture the programs run on. Even if you don't have a similar computer, you can build a suitable cross version of gdb (if I recall correctly; it is a while since I cross-compiled code and needed to debug it).

Comment: The other "normal" approach is to request an interactive session, that would give you access to the same type of node, and then run the program with the same memory and stack size limits as the batch job under the control of a debugger.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks for your suggestion. I have already done exactly the same, but unfortunately the program works perfectly in the interactive way!

Comment: Were the (virtual) memory/stack/locked memory size limits the same as for your batch jobs? Stack space exhaustion is the number one trivial reason for misterious segmentation faults in threaded applications.

Comment: @HristoIliev This was the first thing I checked!

Comment: @DietmarKühl I tried to check the core files, they are created but empty!