# CaptureStackBackTrace on Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I've recently heard about the [CaptureStackBackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204633(VS.85).aspx) function by reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c).  I cannot find it in any of my Visual Studio 2005 header files however, and I'm guessing (from the MSDN URL which mentions VS.85) that this may only be a Visual Studio 2008 thing.

Is there a way, perhaps by manually finding the entry point in a system DLL somewhere, to get this function under Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your Windows SDK to the most recent version? Since this is a Windows API function, it should be included there.

Answer (score 3):

> Remarks
>
> The CaptureStackBackTrace function is
>   defined as the
>   RtlCaptureStackBackTrace function. For
>   more information, see Winbase.h and
>   Winnt.h.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't updated my Windows SDK beyond whatever comes with Visual Studio 2005 but I have found this solution to work:

```
typedef USHORT (WINAPI *CaptureStackBackTraceType)(__in ULONG, __in ULONG, __out PVOID*, __out_opt PULONG);
CaptureStackBackTraceType func = (CaptureStackBackTraceType)(GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll"), "RtlCaptureStackBackTrace"));
// Then use 'func' as if it were CaptureStackBackTrace
```