# Finding the function caller in C

Tags: c, function

Hey all, I'm just wondering if it is possible to get the name of the program thats running within a function?

Here's an example:

Say I called: **./runProgram**

```
main() {

A();

}

function A() {

// Possible to retrieve "runProgram" if I cannot use main's argc(argv) constants??
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You state that you "cannot use main's argc(argv) constants" but it is unclear whether: (1) you did not realise that you can easily store or pass as parameters argc/argv from main() to somewhere else; or (2) whether there is some technical restriction preventing you from using argc/argv at all.

Comment: If there's a technical reason, it's a much more interesting question ;-p
For example perhaps the function is in a plugin to an existing program, so the signature or main() can't be changed...

Comment: oh, haven't noticed he uses the zero param main version oO

Comment: 10 answers for something pretty stupid. We really need better questions around here =/

Comment: @toto: come on... questions like this are my insanity's playground.

Comment: @toto - you're right this was a terribly stupid question haha. though my motives we're clear and evil - beat my CS projects test scripts! Ended up just figuring it out the project on my own though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler dependent, so:

```
$ cc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)
```

Make the program

```
$ more x.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      printf("program: %s\n", argv[0]);
    foo();
}


int foo() {    
}

$ make x
cc     x.c   -o x
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
$ ./x 
program: ./x
```

Get the global name of the argc/v vars

```
$ nm ./x
0000000100000efe s  stub helpers
0000000100001048 D _NXArgc
0000000100001050 D _NXArgv
0000000100001060 D ___progname
0000000100000000 A __mh_execute_header
0000000100001058 D _environ
                 U _exit
0000000100000eeb T _foo
0000000100000eb8 T _main
                 U _printf
0000000100001020 s _pvars
                 U dyld_stub_binder
0000000100000e7c T start
```

Add the global name, declared as extern, and keep into account the mangling.

```
$ more x2.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      printf("program: %s\n", argv[0]);
    foo();
}


int foo() {
    extern char **NXArgv;
    printf("in foo: %s\n", NXArgv[0]);

}
```

Run the horror

```
$ make x2
cc     x2.c   -o x2
x2.c: In function ‘main’:
x2.c:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
x2.c: In function ‘foo’:
x2.c:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
$ ./x2 
program: ./x2
in foo: ./x2
```

Please don't tell my mom.

Comment: Despite all these other evils, you could at least `#include <stdio.h>` and get the compiler to shut up. It couldn't hurt.

Comment: @Chris: I was in a hurry. And yes, I could have added the header, but it was much better to add a 2>&1 >/dev/null considering the trend of the answer...

Comment: Hahaha. First of all I actually Lol'ed at both "Please don't tell my mom" and "You're a wild man". Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible in "standard C". If you are into jiggery-pokery, you may be able to look at the environment variables of the program to find the command line. The following works on FreeBSD:

```
/*    _ _                                               _                   
     (_|_) __ _  __ _  ___ _ __ _   _       _ __   ___ | | _____ _ __ _   _ 
     | | |/ _` |/ _` |/ _ \ '__| | | |_____| '_ \ / _ \| |/ / _ \ '__| | | |
     | | | (_| | (_| |  __/ |  | |_| |_____| |_) | (_) |   <  __/ |  | |_| |
    _/ |_|\__, |\__, |\___|_|   \__, |     | .__/ \___/|_|\_\___|_|   \__, |
   |__/   |___/ |___/           |___/      |_|                        |___/  */

#include <stdio.h>

extern char ** environ;

void A ()
{
    char ** p;
    for (p = environ; *p; p++)
        printf ("%s\n", * p);
}

int main ()
{
    A ();
}
```

However, in C itself, unlike languages like JavaScript and Perl, there is no way to take a peek up the stack and find out who called you.

Comment: I think I was pretty careful to qualify that is "in C itself", not in a particular compiler.

Answer (score 3):

`GetCurrentProcessId();` will get you the current Process ID.  From there, you will need to match this up with the currently running process name.

See [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/getprocessid.aspx) for more information on step #2.

Comment: Calling GetModuleFileName with NULL as the first parameter would be much more direct

Answer (score 1):

Typically what you would do is use a global variable for this.

```
const char *g_argv0;
void A()
{
    printf("program is %s\n", g_argv0);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    g_argv0 = argv[0];
    A();
    return 0;
}
```

With trivial variations on this idea, you can save the entire command line array in a global variable if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the program will be stored in argv[0].

Note that this is not necessarily the same as the filename that first comes to mind.  E.g., if there are symbolic links to the program and the program was invoked using that name, then that is what will be stored in argv[0].

So, for example, you could use the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

which would yield the following behavior:

```
$ cc t.c
$ ./a.out 
./a.out
$ ln -s a.out foo
$ ./foo
./foo
```

Note that shell substitutions occur before the name reaches the program:

```
$ alias bar=./foo
$ bar
./foo
```

Comment: OP specificaly asked for a way to do this without using argv

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact that your code above is terrible C and is actually closer to pseudocode...

No. You can either assign `argv[0]` to a global variable so it can be accessed by code elsewhere, or you can pass it as an argument. I doubt there's a standard C way to get into the local variables of another function. It sounds like a  rather bad idea anway (in my humble opinion).

Using a global:

```
char *progname;

void A(void)
{
    // do stuff with progname
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    progname = *argv;
    A();
    return 0;
}
```

Passing as an argument:

```
void A(char *progname)
{
    // do stuff with progname
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A(*argv);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Most of us missed it because it was hidden rather deceptively in the comments, but you say you can't use `argv`. I just want to note that any solution not using `argv` is going to be non-portable, and that the best answer is to go ahead and use `argv` since it's given to you by the standard and there's no conceivable reason you *can't* use `argv`. That's like saying "How can I print text to the console without using the `stdin` filehandle?" You can do it, but why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("program: %s\n", argv[0]);

  //pass argv[0] to the desired function.
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking.

Comment: It's certainly a better way to achieve the goal than what he's asking for.

Comment: He specifically said that he did not have access to the args

Comment: @Chris: Intriguing... how can you end-up in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows you could use the GetCommandLine function. Maybe there's a similar API for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find the complete command that resulted in your process' execution from a getpid, but the specifics as to how that might be done are going to vary from platform to platform.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you can look at `/proc/self/cmdline` (or alternatively find the process ID with `getpid()` and then look at `/proc/[pid]/cmdline`; the former is a shortcut to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

C calling convention on x86 has a stack frame layout like this.

```
                               ...
                   *0x4000000c  =  0x60000000  (2nd argument)
                   *0x40000008  =  0x00000001  (1st argument)
                   *0x40000004  =  0x20000000  (return address)
*(old %esp = %ebp = 0x40000000) =  0x3ffffff0  (old %ebp)
                   *0x3ffffffc  =  0x00000000  (1st local)
                   *0x3ffffff8  =  0x00000000  (2nd local)
                               ...
           *(%esp = 0x3ffffff0)                (end of frame)
```

Therefore, to get the caller's arguments, start from `(%ebp)` and walk up.  GCC's `__builtin_frame_address` extension helps with the first step.

```
A() {
    void **ebp = __builtin_frame_address(1);
    void **ra = ebp + 1;
    int *argc = ra + 1;
    char ***argv = argc + 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *argc; i++) printf("[%d] %s\n", i, (*argv)[i]);
}
a(int argc, char **argv) { A(); }
main(int argc, char **argv) { a(argc, argv); }
```

Unfortunately, `main` is a bit special, so calling `A` directly from `main` will likely crash.

Also, to save work and free up a register, optimizing compilers will may omit this standard stack frame setup, which would also cause this to fail.