# Getting the address of the function that called my function with inline assembly

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I would like to know how to retrieve the address of the function that called my function with inline assembly. My idea is to get the address to where the function that called mine will return and using the instruction before it (that is a call to the function that called mine) retrieving the address of the one that called mine adding to the offset given to that call, to the address of the next instruction (the address to where the function that called mine will return). So far I was able to make this but to get the address of mine. It is fairly simple and it works:

```
_asm
{
    mov eax, [ebp+4]
    mov returnTo,eax
}

long addressOfMine = (*((long*)(returnTo - sizeof(long)))) + returnTo)
```

This retrieves the address of mine just fine. (By knowing that [ebp+4] is the address to where mine will return)

To do the same but one step above I tried to get the old ebp and do the same. I saw in a site that [ebp+0] is the old ebp so I tried:

```
_asm
{ 
    mov eax, [ebp]
    mov ebx, [eax+4]
    mov returnTo,ebx
}

long addressOfCaller = (*((long*)(returnTo - sizeof(long)))) + returnTo)
```

But it doesn't work. So, my assumption is wrong or I'm doing something wrong so I would like to ask your help.

Comment: You know, with global, cross-function optimization there may be some really interesting problems here.  If a compiler is doing cross-function CSE, the code might not strictly lie in any user-defined function.

Comment: I understand that things are not always plain but the truth is that my function will return to a function and that function will return to another. So, the value that I want must be somewhere.

Comment: If it's inlined it is no longer a function. But they aren't.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I hope it's not for some misguided attempt at security: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/01/47042.aspx

Comment: Also, my x86 is a bit fuzzy, but isn't `[ebp+4]` exactly what you're looking for?  It should be the value which was pushed onto the stack just before the function was called - that is, the return-point in the function that called you.  There is no way to get the start-address of that function, though, as the "start" of a subroutine is not something that's reall well-defined in ASM.  You could try passing function pointers around?

Comment: [ebp+4] is the address to where my function returns. So the value I retrieve in the call before it is the address of mine. I want to do this one step above.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  No, there is no way of knowing that without knowing the size of the stack of the function which called you (which is not something you can determine at runtime).  Perhaps there is a better way of solving whatever problem you are trying to solve with this - what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: What you said may make sense but I'm not conviced. What I want to do is "To know the address of the function that called mine"

Comment: I understand that; but since I'm fairly certain the answer is "it can't be done," perhaps I can help you find a different solution to whatever problem it is you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: "Not your business"? That's just silly. Answering your question isn't any of our business either. We do it out of interest. Drop the attitude, please

Comment: -1 Marked your comment offensive. We aren't your bell boys to service you with programming answers. We are a group of people that happen to enjoy answering programming questions. Until you start paying us, you can't be rude like that. (even then, most people wouldn't take it.)

Comment: Whoa. I don't care what kind of application you're trying to write, but it's easier to help someone solve their problem when you have some idea of what problem they're *really* trying to solve, not just a half-working solution to an unstated problem. For example, "I want to record/display the call stack" would get a different response than "I want to write my own stack walking function as a learning exercise". With the first question, if you step back, you can approach it an easier way: "Is there a function that will give me a stack backtrace so I don't have to write my own?"

Comment: Nothing to do with this. The question is simple "How to get the address of the function that called mine".

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so as long as you know you are doing something non-portable.  You know that right?

I mean, it's not like a dozen people haven't said it already...

so. for functions on x86 (but not X64) when frame pointer omission and other optimizations aren't enabled, this should work.  doesn't work for all calling conventions, but it should work for standard C/C++ calling convention.

```
void ** puEBP = NULL;
__asm { mov puEBP, ebp };
void * pvReturn = puEBP[1]; // this is the caller of my function

puEBP = (void**)puEBP[0];    // walk back to the previous frame
void * pvReturn2 = puEBP[1]; // this is the caller's caller
```

edit: Ok I'm officially confused now.  I looked again at your question, and as far as I can tell, the your first code fragment is functionally the same as what I just wrote.  But you say that that code gives you the address of your function - but that shouldn't be true.  that code fragment *should* be returning the address of the caller to your function.

edit2: added code to get the caller of the caller.

By the way this code that you show in your question

```
long addressOfCaller = (*((long*)(returnTo - sizeof(long)))) + returnTo)
```

won't work.  It's based on the assumption that the only way to make a call is

```
call symbol
```

where symbol is a 4 byte absolute address of a function. 
But thats not the only way to make a call.  it's also possible to call indirect

```
mov eax, symbol
call [eax]
```

or

```
call [ref_symbol]
```

And it also possible to call relative to the current instruction

```
call +12
```

But you don't need to do this, once you know any address within the calling function, you can use the [Debug Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(VS.85).aspx) to find the address of the function that called you.

In order to use DebugHelp, you must have the debug symbols for the code. then just use 
[SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681323(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Ok. that's clearer now.  You want the caller of your caller.  ok.

Comment: Unknown: See my latest edit.  I've verified this code in the debuffer this with compiler optimizations turned off.

Comment: I understand the issue on what I'm assuming. Anyway i resorted to use os API to do what i want. In linux it was easy. In windows i'm still figuring out on how to use StackWalk64 function.

Comment: But your problem isn't walking the stack.  Your problem is that there is no way to convert a return address into the address of the caller.

Comment: I want to get the address of the caller. The "way to" doesn't matter.

Comment: and knowing an address _within_ the calling function is not good enough?

Comment: no because I want to use that address as a function pointer (so I can call it or hook it)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use the function provided by your OS? here are a pair of links [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

You may try something more complicated http://www.yosefk.com/blog/getting-the-call-stack-without-a-frame-pointer.html

But you have to be aware that in x86 mode the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) are not easier, it depends on some factors like your OS, your compiler, the calling convention used, etc.

Comment: I don't want the name of the function that called mine to be displayed. I want to get its address so I can use it. I will check out your second link.

Comment: In order to get the name of the function you first need the address of  it.

Comment: Check the first link to understand what I said

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to do. You must know how many arguments and local variables the caller has, which in most cases, is not trivial to figure out programmatically. If you make the possibly wrong assumption that the compiler keeps `EBP` as the stackframe holder and never alters it(as in, this wouldn't work with -O3/2/1 probably)

inside of the called function, you could do something like

```
mov ecx,ebp ;save our current stack frame
pop ebp ;get the old value of EBP that was there before our function got called
mov dword [_caller_address],dword [ebp+4] ;this isn't actually a valid opcode. you figure it out. 
mov ebp,ecx ;restore old state
push ebp
```

This is very unsafe though. Optimizations on the compiler will probably break it. It will only work for x86-32, and depending on OS and compiler it may not work if it follows a different calling standard.

The way it works is this:

Functions in C look something like

```
_Sum:
        push    ebp             ; create stack frame
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ; grab the first argument
        mov     ecx, [ebp+12]   ; grab the second argument
        add     eax, ecx        ; sum the arguments
        pop     ebp             ; restore the base pointer
        ret
```

So, if say you had _SumCall it'd look somethign like

```
_SumCall:
        push    ebp             ; create stack frame
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ; grab the first argument
        mov     ecx, [ebp+12]   ; grab the second argument
        push ecx ;first argument for call
        push eax ;second argument for call
        call _Sum
        pop     ebp             ; restore the base pointer
        ret
```

So you see, it relies on the fact that the callee is responsible for stack frame preservation.

If you try it and it doesn't work, ensure both the caller and callee have at least 1 local variable/argument. Failing that, then well, your just screwed because the compiler made some optimization that broke this assumption.

Once again. This is **very unsafe and is extremely not-portable**

Reference: http://courses.ece.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html

Comment: It didn't work for me with -O2 and I can't discard optimizations because the library where the caller is contained is not mine. In linux it was really easy. Just one call to "int backtrace (void **buffer, int size)". In windows I guess "StackWalk64" is my solution but haven't managed to make it work yet.

Comment: Even then it is not safe because how do you know what in the stack is a function call? What you are asking for is something that is not trivially solvable.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea for you "unknown (google)". Retrieve the address of where your function will return to, patch that address to do "get to where it returns and call a function of yours passing you that value", return, and in your callback use the argument you receive and fix what you patched with the original values.

By the way, I'm hoping you are not using this to invade the Pentagon computers.

Answer (score 0):

What about something a bit more straight ? *Not sure if it works on any platform/CPU:

```
void adr(void *x)
{
    *(void**)x = *(&x - 1); // x points to input parameter pushed before call
}

void *x;
adr(&x); // sets return adress to x
```