# From where starts the process' memory space and where does it end?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

On Windows platform, I'm trying to dump memory from my application where the variables lie. Here's the function:

```
void MyDump(const void *m, unsigned int n)
{
        const unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(m);
        char buffer[16];
        unsigned int mod = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++mod) {
                if (mod % 16 == 0) {
                        mod = 0;

                        std::cout << " | ";

                        for (unsigned short j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
                                switch (buffer[j]) {
                                        case 0xa:
                                        case 0xb:
                                        case 0xd:
                                        case 0xe:
                                        case 0xf:
                                                std::cout << " ";

                                                break;

                                        default: std::cout << buffer[j];
                                }
                        }

                        std::cout << "\n0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << (long)i << " | ";
                 }

                buffer[i % 16] = p[i];

                std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(p[i]) << " ";

                if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 1)
                        std::cout << " ";
        }
}
```

Now, how can I know from which address starts my process memory space, where all the variables are stored? And how do I now, how long the area is?

For instance:

```
MyDump(0x0000 /* <-- Starts from here? */, 0x1000 /* <-- This much? */);
```

Best regards,
nhaa123

Comment: On what sort of computer and operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

What you're trying to do is absolutely possible, and there are even tools to help, but you'll have to do more legwork than I think you're expecting.

In your case, you're particularly interested in "where the variables lie." The [system heap API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366710.aspx) on Windows will be an incredible help to you. The reference is really quite good, and though it won't be a single contiguous region the API will tell you where your variables are.

In general, though, not knowing anything about where your memory is laid out, you're going to have to do a sweep of the entire address space of the process. If you want only data, you'll have to do some filtering of that, too, because code and stack nonsense are also there. Lastly, to avoid seg-faulting while you dump the address space, you may need to add a segfault signal handler that lets you skip unmapped memory while you're dumping.

### Process Memory Layout

What you will have, in a running process, is *multiple disjoint stretches* of memory to print out. They will include:

1. Compiled code (read-only),
2. Stack data (local variables),
3. Static Globals (e.g. from shared libraries or in your program), and
4. Dynamic heap data (everything from `malloc` or `new`).

The key to a reasonable dump of memory is being able to tell which range of addresses belongs to which family. That's your main job, when you're dumping the program. Some of this, you can do by reading the addresses of functions (1) and variables (2, 3 and 4), but if you want to print more than a few things, you'll need some help.

For this, we have...

### Useful Tools

Rather than just blindly searching the address space from 0 to 2^64 (which, we all know, is painfully huge), you will want to employ OS and compiler developer tools to narrow down your search. Someone out there needs these tools, maybe even more than you do; it's just a matter of finding them. Here are a few of which I'm aware.

*Disclaimer: I don't know many of the Windows equivalents for many of these things, though I'm sure they exist somewhere.*

I've already mentioned the Windows [system heap API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366710.aspx). This is a best-case scenario for you. The more things you can find in this vein, the more accurate and easy your dump will be. Really, the OS and the C runtime know quite a bit about your program. It's a matter of extracting the information.

On Linux, memory types 1 and 3 are accessible through utilities like /proc/pid/maps. In /proc/pid/maps you can see the ranges of the address space reserved for libraries and program code. You can also see the protection bits; read-only ranges, for instance, are probably code, not data.

For Windows tips, Mark Russinovich has [written some articles](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) on how to learn about a Windows process's address space and where different things are stored. I imagine he might have some good pointers in there.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer to this question is you cannot approach this problem this way.  The way processes are laid out in memory is very much compiler and operating system dependent, and there is no easy to to determine where all of the code and variables lie.  To accurately and completely find all of the variables, you'd need to write large portions of a debugger yourself (or borrow them from a real debugger's code).

But, you could perhaps narrow the scope of your question a little bit.  If what you really want is just a stack trace, those are not too hard to generate: [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

Or if you want to examine the stack itself, it is easy to get a pointer to the current top of the stack (just declare a local variable and then take it's address).  Tthe easiest way to get the bottom of the stack is to declare a variable in main, store it's address in a global variable, and use that address later as the "bottom" (this is easy but not really 'clean').

Getting a picture of the heap is a lot lot lot harder, because you need extensive knowledge of the internal workings of the heap to know which pieces of it are currently allocated.  Since the heap is basically "unlimited" in size, that's quite  alot of data to print if you just print all of it, even the unused parts.  I don't know of a way to do this, and I would highly recommend you not waste time trying.

Getting a picture of static global variables is not as bad as the heap, but also difficult.  These live in the data segments of the executable, and unless you want to get into some assembly and parsing of executable formats, just avoid doing this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't, not really... at least not in a portable manner. For the stack, you could do something like:

```
void* ptr_to_start_of_stack = 0;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int item_at_approximately_start_of_stack;
    ptr_to_start_of_stack = &item_at_approximately_start_of_stack;
    // ... 
    // ... do lots of computation
    // ... a  function called here can do something similar, and
    // ... attempt to print out from ptr_to_start_of_stack to its own
    // ... approximate start of stack
    // ... 
    return 0;
}
```

In terms of attempting to look at the range of the heap, on many systems, you could use the [sbrk()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/brk.html) function (specifically `sbrk(0)`) to get a pointer to the start of the heap (typically, it grows upward starting from the end of the address space, while the stack typically grows down  from the start of the address space).

That said, **this is a really bad idea**. Not only is it platform dependent, but the information you can get from it is really not as useful as good logging. I suggest you familiarize yourself with [Log4Cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/).

Good logging practice, in addition to the use of a debugger such as GDB, is really the best way to go. Trying to debug your program by looking at a full memory dump is like trying to find a needle in a haystack, and so it really is not as useful as you might think. Logging where the problem might logically be, is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this depends on OS, you should look at e.g. memory segmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running on a mainstream operating system.  You'll need help from the operating system to find out which addresses in your virtual memory space have mapped pages.  For example, on Windows you'd use VirtualQueryEx().  The memory dump you'll get can be as large as two gigabytes, it isn't that likely you discover anything recognizable quickly.

Your debugger already allows you to inspect memory at arbitrary addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not portably. And you can't make many assumptions either.

Unless you're running this on CP/M or MS-DOS.

But with modern systems, the where and hows of where you data and code are located, in the generic case, aren't really up to you.

You can play linker games, and such to get better control of the memory map for you executable, but you won't have any control over, say, any shared libraries you may load, etc.

There's no guarantee that any of your code, for example, is even in a continuous space. The Virtual Memory and loader can place code pretty much where it wants. Nor is there any guarantee that your data is anywhere near your code. In fact, there's no guarantee that you can even READ the memory space where your code lives. (Execute, yes. Read, maybe not.)

At a high level, your program is split in to 3 sections: code, data, and stack. The OS places these where it sees fit, and the memory manager controls what and where you can see stuff.

There are all sorts of things that can muddy these waters.

However.

If you want.

You can try having "markers" in your code. For example, put a function at the start of your file called "startHere()" and then one at the end called "endHere()". If you're lucky, for a single file program, you'll have a continuous blob of code between the function pointers for "startHere" and "endHere".

Same thing with static data. You can try the same concept if you're interested in that at all.