# Is there a way to know the name of class from which a method of an object is being called in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose in a method MA() of class A, a method MB() of class B is being called after creation of an object. Is there a way to know in MB() the name of the class and the method from which it is being called in C++ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is a [Stack Trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Stack Trace definition:

> The stack trace is a useful debugging
>   tool that you'll normally take
>   advantage of when an exception has
>   been thrown. It provides information
>   on the execution history of the
>   current thread, displaying the names
>   of the classes and methods within
>   those classes that had been called at
>   the point when the exception occurred.

This SO question on ["How can one grab a stack trace in C?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c) has the answer you need.

Comment: +1 for this, but worth noting that C++ doesn't provide any features for or guarantees about the portable availability of stack inspection mechanisms

Comment: And probably it work such simplistically only with builds which have symbol information. It would take lot more efforts if it is a release build without symbol information

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and more generic way would be as follows:

a) Enable output tracing based on a run time condition (e.g. a particular environment variable) / debug switch

b) Log the entry and exit of each function along with thread id (to take care of multi threaded applications). For this use the `__FILE__ and __LINE__` preprocessor directives.

c) Analyze the logs using a good logviewer application (e.g. DebugView on Windows)