# How to get call stack in c in windows?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

In PHP it's `debug_backtrace`,is there such a function in c?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can call the [`StackWalk64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650%28VS.85%29.aspx) function that is exported by `DBGHELP.DLL`. It is shipped with Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg) but according to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679294%28VS.85%29.aspx), "The redistribution policies for these included DLLs were specifically designed to make it as easy as possible for people to include these files in their own packages and releases."