# Is it possible to debug-print the caller of the current function?

Tags: c++, debugging, callstack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899870/print-call-stack-in-c-or-c)

Often times when debugging code I need to figure out who is calling the function that I have placed a debug statement in.  I know that `__FUNCTION__` evaluates to the name of the current function, but is there something similar that will give me the name of the callee?  Or maybe print out the call stack?

The information must be available.  If I put in an assert or code that will segfault, I get a stack trace that shows the entire call stack.  Where does the stack trace-printing code get that information?

If you are unable to produce a platform-agnostic solution, then something that will work on x86_64 Ubuntu 12.04 compiled with `gcc` will do.  Bonus points for providing solutions for other platforms as well.

Comment: There's no universal solution. Which platform do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OS-dependent.

On Linux and gcc, use `backtrace(3)`. For Windows, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693192/win32-backtrace-from-c-code).

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace gets that information by walking the call stack looking for return addresses and pawing through the executable to find which function a return address returns to. Nothing portable there. No general way to find the caller. The best you can do is run under a debugger and set a breakpoint to trigger when the debug code fires.

Also, `__FUNCTION__` is not part of Standard C++. Seems to me it's a GNU thing.

Comment: The standard version of `__FUNCTION__` is `__func__` btw.

Comment: @chris - not in my copy of the standard. <g>

Comment: Really? The C++11 one has it in § 8.4.2/8.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNC__` are implemented by most compilers, even if they are non-standard.

Comment: @chris - you're right. Sorry. (Minor nit: it's 8.4.1/8, not 8.4.2/8).

Comment: @PeteBecker, Oops, yeah, I scrolled down to the bottom of the page for it and didn't check if a new section had started >.>

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give you the *name* of the caller, but the intrinsic function `_ReturnAddress()` usually returns a pointer that points back to the caller.