# How can I get the filename and line number when Backtracing?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, backtrace

I saw a very good way to get the symbol name from the following post.

[Win32 - Backtrace from C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693192/win32-backtrace-from-c-code)

But what about getting the file name and line number. I tried to use the SymGetLineFromAddr64 but could not get this debug information.

Comment: What did you try? Is your binary built with debugging information?

Comment: Yes it is built with debug information, when I used GetLastError function to get the last error. I got 0xc0000005.

Comment: What I mean is...can you post the code you tried? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) preferred.

Answer (score 4):

If you couldn't get this debug information, and your code was correct, then the problem could be with the options. You need `SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES` to have this information loaded:

```
SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);
```

Then, supposing you are using the code from the link you provided, it would be like this:

```
DWORD  dwDisplacement;
IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line;

SymGetLineFromAddr64(process, (DWORD64)stack[i], &dwDisplacement, &line);
```

Now you can access these `line` members (from the [IMAGEHLP_LINE64 structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680190.aspx)):

```
DWORD   LineNumber;
PTSTR   FileName;
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved my issue. I was passing NULL to third parameter because it was optional in SymFromAddr so I assumed the same for this function.

Comment: There are many API functions where we have optional parameters, but it's always safe to pass a non-null pointer to them. Another example of function with this kind of parameter, is `CreateThread`, where the `threadID` parameter is optional (and many others), and some people just pass `NULL` to it, but others pass  pointer. IMHO, I like to always pass a valid pointer for safety reasons. Of course if you know the API function well, you can do whatever you want with it, but in doubt, do the safe way.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. it happened with me because I just wanted to save few seconds which I could save at the end:) And both functions signatures were so similar (except the last parameter) that I could not think this way.