# SymFromAddr returns ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS flag, how to get stack trace in mingw?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, winapi, backtrace

All I try to do is to print stack of methods that called a given line. I got code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5699483/393087 answer. Slightly refactored it to show where lies the problem.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <imagehlp.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>

void printStack( void ) {
  HMODULE dbghelp_lib = LoadLibrary("dbghelp.dll");
  if (NULL == dbghelp_lib) {
    printf("dbghelp.dll failed");
  }
  HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
  if (!SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE )) {
    printf("SymInitialize failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    abort();
  } else SetLastError(0);
  void * stack[100];
  ULONG FramesToSkip = 0;
  ULONG FramesToCapture = 32;
  unsigned short frames = CaptureStackBackTrace( FramesToSkip, FramesToCapture, stack, NULL );
  SYMBOL_INFO * symbol;
  symbol = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
  symbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
  symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO );
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < frames; i++ ) {
    if(!SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol )) {
      printf("SymFromAddr failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    printf( "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address );
  }
  free( symbol );
}

void testfunc() {
  printStack();
}

int main() {
  testfunc();
}
```

it returns:

```
SymFromAddr failed: 487
3:  - 0x0
SymFromAddr failed: 487
2:  - 0x0
SymFromAddr failed: 487
1:  - 0x0
0: RegisterWaitForInputIdle - 0x7C81702E
```

And it compiles and links without any warning.

compiler: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev7.7z

Comment: I wonder if dbghelp at all supports non-microsoft compilers.

Comment: It requires a .pdb file for the process to map addresses to symbols.  Surely you don't have one.

Comment: dbghelp does not support DWARF symbols AFAIK, it only supports PDB

Comment: The answer I'm rewarding is the one that shows how to make SymFromAddr work with MinGW or an equivalent solution that produces symbols.

Comment: I discovered the symbol gets shown if I use __declspec( dllexport ) on the function prototype.

Comment: is it compiled with unwind tables option ?

Answer (score 3):

dbghelp only reads PDB files.   Therefore, your options are:

1. Reimplement dbghelp APIs to use DWARF (probably more work than you want)
2. Convert your DWARF symbols to PDB.

A bit of googling for #2 found [cv2pdb](https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb), which appears to be oriented towards the D programming language, but it seems generic enough that it might be a simpler approach.