# Print stacktrace from C code with embedded lua

Tags: lua, stack-trace, traceback, lua-api

If I understand this correctly, Lua by default will call the debug library "debug.traceback" when an error occurs.

However, when embedding Lua into C code like done in the example here:
[Simple Lua API Example](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaApiExample)

We only have available the error message on the top of the stack.

i.e.

```
if (status) {
    /* If something went wrong, error message is at the top of */
    /* the stack */
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load file: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    /* I want to print a stacktrace here. How do I do that? */
    exit(1);
}
```

How do I print the stack trace from C after the initial error?

Comment: In Lua 5.2 you can use luaL_traceback.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Lua by default will call the debug library "debug.traceback" when an error occurs.

No, it won't. The Lua *runtime* (lua.exe) will do that, but the Lua library will not do that on its own. If you want a call-stack with your Lua errors, then you need to generate one.

The Lua runtime does this by using [`lua_pcall`'s](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pcall) error function. The stack has not been unwound when the error function is called, so you can get a stack trace there. The error function the runtime uses is this one:

```cpp
static int traceback (lua_State *L) {
  if (!lua_isstring(L, 1))  /* 'message' not a string? */
    return 1;  /* keep it intact */
  lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "debug");
  if (!lua_istable(L, -1)) {
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return 1;
  }
  lua_getfield(L, -1, "traceback");
  if (!lua_isfunction(L, -1)) {
    lua_pop(L, 2);
    return 1;
  }
  lua_pushvalue(L, 1);  /* pass error message */
  lua_pushinteger(L, 2);  /* skip this function and traceback */
  lua_call(L, 2, 1);  /* call debug.traceback */
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not really a complete answer.  But I looked up lua.c and that gives the whole picture of how to actually use the traceback function.

Comment: Extending this to walk the C stack would require a lot of platform-specific details, but can certainly be done. It would obviously work best if symbols are available for the executable. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c) provides a bunch of approaches to doing the C side. Stringifying the result and tagging it on to the result of `debug.traceback` is then a straightforward problem.

Answer (score 11):

Working off Nicol’s answer above here is a working example:

```
static int traceback(lua_State *L) {
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "debug");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "traceback");
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 2);
    lua_call(L, 2, 1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);    
    lua_pushcfunction(L, traceback);
    int rv = luaL_loadfile(L, "src/main.lua");
    if (rv) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        return rv;
    } else {
        return lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, lua_gettop(L) - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, **Note** newer lua versions has `lua_getglobal` so need to use `lua_getglobal(L, "debug");`

Comment: If this function prints me "null" in back, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

I met the some question as you do,and I found this way work:

```
luaL_traceback(L, L, NULL, 1);
printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
```

Since`luaL_traceback`is exactly`debug.traceback()` using to print the stack,so I think this may be a proper way,and you can read the API manual about`luaL_traceback` or just read the source code of Lua to figure out the what the params means.

Comment: It seems that this function does not exists in Lua 5.1, which is the version I must use. Too bad. I also don't have debug library loaded to my Lua state running on embedded device.

Answer (score 2):

mxcl's code has some problem:

```
static int traceback(lua_State *L) {
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "debug");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "traceback");
    //---------------------------
    lua_pop(L,-2); //to popup the 'debug'
    //---------------------------
    lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 2);
    lua_call(L, 2, 1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You still wrong, [lua_pop](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pop) Pops n elements from the stack. You should use [lua_remove](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_remove)