# Lua: get stack trace without global methods

Tags: c#, lua

In a game that uses Lua for extensibility, when an error is thrown in a script, I'd like to show the user an error log, i.e. an error message and a stack trace, somewhat like this:

```
if (lua_pcall(L, nargs, nresults, 0) != 0) log.printline(lua_tostring(L, -1));
```

This only prints the error message, though, not the call stack.

I am aware I could use `debug.traceback`, i.e. grabbing the function from the debug table through the API and then calling it, but I don't want to load the debug table at all because of security concerns, i.e. allowing a malicious user to write scripts that screw with the system and other global tables. (For the same reason I don't load `io` and instead expose my own functions.)

I'm not using a bridge of any sort, I use the Lua API directly, through P/Invoke.

How would I go about printing a stack trace following a failed `lua_pcall` call, without having to expose the debug table to the end user?

Comment: You could always sandbox Lua, because I do not believe there's any other way.

Comment: Unless xpcall would help (?) I haven't messed with it much

Comment: You don't have to load the *entire* debug library just to get access to `debug.traceback`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [luaL_traceback](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_traceback):

> `void luaL_traceback (lua_State *L, lua_State *L1, const char *msg, int level);`
>
> Creates and pushes a traceback of the stack L1. If msg is not NULL it is appended at the beginning of the traceback. The level parameter tells at which level to start the traceback.

You probably want to use `L1=L`. See the [source](http://www.lua.org/source/) of `lua.c` for an example of use.

Comment: Looks like luaL_traceback is only available in 5.2 and up. I'm using 5.1, will try and see if I can migrate, was planning to anyway...

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: `luaL_traceback` have been backported to Lua 5.1: https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.2/blob/master/c-api/compat-5.2.c#L226. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256455/print-stacktrace-from-c-code-with-embedded-lua.

Comment: I settled for implementing `luaL_traceback` by having it push `db_errorfb` (which is debug.traceback) on the stack, its arguments, and then calling it through lua_call.

Answer (score 0):

4th argument in lua_pcall is error handler. So you can call some think like `debug.traceback` in this function to get stacktrace and do log in this function.

Comment: I can't call `debug.traceback` from a Lua function because of security concerns. That's kind of the entire problem.