# How to write a logging function or macro that can append caller's name to the logging output in C

Tags: c, logging, macros

I need a logging function or macro in C language, which should works in Linux, that can accept a format string and a list of arguments, and can append the caller's function name to the output string.

Here is an example. Suppose the logging function (macro) is called smart_log. It looks like:

```
smart_log(const char *fmt, ...)
```

The first argument fmt is a format string, just like the format string in printf.
Following fmt is a list of additional arguments to feed fmt.

Suppose a function called example_function calls smart_log in this way:

```
void example_function() {
    smart_log("try to output number %d\n", 1);
}
```

Then the logging string looks like:

```
[example_function]: try to output number 1
```

So the key point is that smart_log append the caller's function to the format string.

I am not sure how to achieve this in C. I think it may be possible to use macro to achieve this.

Comment: Linux, Windows, Mac what is it?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Linux actually. I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no portable way for a function to know its caller in C. But you’re right, a macro works:

```
#define smart_log(...) ( printf("[%s]: ", __func__) , printf(__VA_ARGS__) )
```

`__func__` is defined (C99/C11 6.4.2.2 p.1)

> as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`
>
> appeared, where *function-name* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

---

Thanks to [Hagen von Eitzen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640715/hagen-von-eitzen) for improving my original attempt!

Comment: How about `#define smart_log( ...)  ( printf("[%s]: ", __func__), printf(__VA_ARGS__) )` instead?
 `

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen *Stellar*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen worthy of a couple random answer upticks. I'm throwing that in my snippet lib. Thanks, sir.

Comment: Related: [gcc documentation "Function Names as Strings"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is very system/compiler dependent as the exact incantation to get the function name depends very much on the compiler. For Visual C++, you'd use the macro `__FUNCTION__` to get the current function name at compile time.

In order to make sure you get the correct function name logged without putting the macro into every invocation of `smart_log`, you can invoke your logging function via a macro so the macro that gets you the function name is evaluated in the correct context - if you simple add the macro to the function name, you'll always get the name of your logging function...

So instead of calling this:

```
smart_log("log message");
```

You call:

```
SMART_LOG("log message");
```

Which in turn is defined to:

```
#define SMART_LOG(message) smart_log(__FUNCTION__, message)
```

This is under the assumption that your log function takes the function name as the first parameter, so tweak to suit.

Comment: Good point, it did sound like the OP wanted a solution that would work in C and C++, and I'm not really aware of a portable macro to achieve that unfortunately.

Comment: The recommendation by @PiotrS. in favor of `__func__` also applies to all C99 and C11 compilers for C (since the C tag is currently included).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if `__func__` was available in C99.

Comment: The C++ tag has been removed in the meanwhile, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/597081/1741125) says, `__func__` has been included in C++11.

Comment: @mafso C++11 § 8.4.1 p8, it is indeed defined per the standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use macros you can use the stack for that. The `smart_log` function will be just on top of the function that called it.

See [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Define a macro - SMART_LOG - which passes `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__`, and `__LINE__`  to `smart_log` as arguments. Then whenever you use `SMART_LOG`, it automatically provides `smart_log` with the code location of the caller.  Note however that `__FUNCTION__` is non-standard, but is available in GCC (and Visual C so I'm lead to believe) see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/597081/191492 ).