# How to print call sequence of functions in c?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I'm reading Apache httpd source code, I would like to know when a request come, which function get called first, followed by which function, and so on, is there some easy way to do so?

Something like

```
Waiting client connection...  # a client send a HTTP request
client.c:accept_request() is called
client.c:handle_request() is called
asdf.c:func1() is called
fdsa.c:func2() is called
response.c:send_response() is called
Waiting client connection...
```

Comment: ehh? Isn't is C code? (you tagged so), and AFAIK, C is process oriented...

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to print the call stack at runtime? This isn't possible in standard C.

Comment: For Linux, there is [`backtrace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) .. compile with debugging symbols for meaningful output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one grab a stack trace in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want to see? This can probably be done using `systemtap`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `printf` statement at the beginning of each function

```
printf("Called function: %s\n", __func__);
```

This will print the name of the function when that function is called and this way you will able to know the function call sequence.

Comment: This is the only hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Not an *easy* way no, but there are multiple possibilities:

- if you can run the code then going through it with a debugger or a profiler can help you see what is going on
- again if you can run the code you can add traces to understand the flow of functions

> ```
> printf(">>> entering %s\n", __func__);
> printf("<<< leaving %s\n", __func__);
> ```

- if you cannot run the code then maybe tools like ctags or cscope can help your see which functions are called when (or an IDE like eclipse or intellij)